# Python: name 'entry1 ' is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I've written a code, which saves the background color of the window in the file, and after closing and running the program again it remembers the window colour (it saves in the file called 'data.txt').

```
# import modules

from tkinter import*  
from tkinter import messagebox as mb
import os.path

# create a window 
w=Tk()
w.title('My Application')
w.resizable(0,0)
w.geometry('300x300')


# Read files

if not(os.path.exists('data.txt')):       #check is the file exists
    print('file does not exists')
    file = open("data.txt",'w')
    file.close()

file = open("data.txt",'r')  #open a file


filelen=len(file.read())
print(len(file.read()))             #length of the file
file.close()


file = open("data.txt",'a')

print('file length is', filelen)
if filelen==0:               #if the file if empty, write default values
    file.write('0 \n0 \n0')            
    print('written to file')
file.close()

file = open("data.txt", 'r')


a=(file.readlines())


e1=float(a[0].replace(' \n',' '))
e2=float(a[1].replace(' \n',' '))    # remove '\n'
e3=float(a[2].replace(' \n',' '))



def _from_rgb(rgb):
    """translates an rgb tuple of int to a tkinter friendly color code
    """
    return "#%02x%02x%02x" % rgb   


file.close()

w.configure(background=_from_rgb((int(e1), int(e2), int(e3))))   #change the bg color to values from the file


def show_settings():

    settings=Tk()
    settings.geometry('400x200')

    entry1=Entry(settings)
    entry2=Entry(settings)
    entry3=Entry(settings)

    entry1.grid(row=1, column=1)
    entry2.grid(row=2, column=1)
    entry3.grid(row=3, column=1)

    changeInfo1=Label(settings,text='Red:',padx=20).grid(row=1, column=0)
    changeInfo2=Label(settings,text='Green:',padx=20).grid(row=2, column=0)
    changeInfo3=Label(settings,text='Blue',padx=20).grid(row=3, column=0)

    entry1.insert(1,e1)
    entry2.insert(1,e2)
    entry3.insert(1,e3)

    print(entry1.get())

    save=Button(settings,text='SAVE!',command=settings_save)
    save.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=2)


def settings_save():                     #save values to a file
    file = open("data.txt",'a')
    file.write('\n' + str(entry1.get()) + ' \n' + str(entry2.get()) + '\n' + str(entry3.get()))
    file.close()


button=Button(w,text='Settings', command=show_settings).pack()
w.mainloop()
```

When i run it, it works, but when i click 'SAVE!' button in settings window it says:

```
 File "C:/Users *filepath*", line 89, in settings_save
        file.write('\n' + str(entry1.get()) + ' \n' + str(entry2.get()) + '\n' + str(entry3.get()))
    NameError: name 'entry1' is not defined
```

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `entry1` object is local to the `show_settings()` method, so it is not visible within `settings_save()`

Move the object into the class and it will be visible

```
# import modules

from tkinter import*  
from tkinter import messagebox as mb
import os.path

...
entry1 = None;
entry2 = None;
entry3 = None;
...

def show_settings():

    settings=Tk()
    settings.geometry('400x200')

    entry1=Entry(settings)
    entry2=Entry(settings)
    entry3=Entry(settings)

   ...

    save=Button(settings,text='SAVE!',command=settings_save)
    save.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=2)


def settings_save():                     #save values to a file
    file = open("data.txt",'a')
    file.write('\n' + str(entry1.get()) + ' \n' + str(entry2.get()) + '\n' + str(entry3.get()))
    file.close()

...

w.mainloop()
```

Comment: Could you please explain, what specific i need to move under a class?

Comment: look at the 3 lines at the top --- `entry1 = None` etc -- it moves the variable out of the method and into the class, making them visible to the other methods

Comment: The https://stackoverflow.com/users/4889267/ak47 's method works, but when i try to get inputs from entry (entry.get()), it returns an empty field